# C# Types of files

Tags: c#, file

Besides a .txt, where else i can insert data using C# ?

```
string file = GenerarPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, "Pascal Triangle.txt");
var tw = new StreamWriter(file);

Console.WriteLine("\t\t Pascal Triangle in C#");
Console.WriteLine("\t________________________________________");
Console.Write("\nNumber of Rows: ");
int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int x = number * 2;
for (int i = 0; i <= number; ++i, x -= 2)
{
    for (int s = 0; s <= x; ++s)
         tw.Write(" ");
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; ++k)
         //Console.Write(String.Format("{0,4:D}", formula(i, k)));
    tw.Write(String.Format("{0,4:D}",pascal(i,k)));//formula(i, k)));
    tw.WriteLine();
}
tw.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Thank you

Comment: It is a bit unclear what is being asked; do you mean binary files?

Comment: anywhere? xml, database, webservice, binary filetypes... good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Almost anywhere. like databases (Sqlserver, access), word files, txt files as you have done.

Comment: The problem is when i print the triangle in a .txt it begins to lose a triangle form, i was thinking to print the data in a excel worksheet or other type of file and i can't insert in any DB.

Comment: why do you want to print the triangle in a text file?

Comment: No matter where i print the pascal's triangle, as long as be a file it's OK, I have to do it for a school practice